# how to only use pyflakes checks with pep8 (never style checks)?

Tags: python, pep8, flake8, pyflakes

I'm migrating from pyflakes to flake8 to get the `# noqa` line ignore feature.  To ease the migration, I'd like to start with only checking whatever pyflakes was previously checking, and I like pyflakes simple promise to ["will never complain about style"](https://github.com/PyCQA/pyflakes#design-principles).  Can I just use `flake8 --select F` to start with whatever was reported by pyflakes?

flake8 allows selecting or disabling specific error codes like `F401` "module imported but unused".  What does `F` stand for?

The [flake8 error-code documentation](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/error-codes.html) doesn't list all error codes.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, to only use pyflakes:

```
flake8 --select F
```

---

flake8 documents the `F` and `C` "classes" on the [pyflakes glossary](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/glossary.html):

- `F`: pyflakes lint checks; [some documented by flake8](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/error-codes.html)
- `C`: mccabe complexity, [currently only `C901`](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/error-codes.html)
- `W` and `E`: [pep8](http://pep8.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes) violations [documented by pycodestyle](https://pycodestyle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes)

  - `E999` is not a pep error; ["We report E999 when we fail to compile a file into an Abstract Syntax Tree for the plugins that require it"](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/error-codes.html)